# Google App Engine, getting started

Tags: google-app-engine, ide

I have wanted to try GAE since launch, but coming from ASP .NET and VS, I couldn't find development tools I feel comfortable with.

As I want to use this to get comfortable with non-Microsoft technologies, I don't care which language I use, be it Java or Python, plus having no idea about any of them I hope this is a good form of taking my first steps in.

What I just want to know are options for development tools and where to dig for information.

And, of course, if I'm of the hook, I will be happy to hear any idea to get on track.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, thanks for the help. Using python and eclipse (with pydev). I'm not really skilled yet, but feel a little confortable with it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse is the best IDE to use for both Python and Java. There is the the eclipse plugin at http://code.google.com/eclipse/ for Java and there is PyDev for Python at http://pydev.sourceforge.net/

Comment: PyDeve now support app engine

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend getting the book [Using Google App Engine](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596800697/) by O'Reilly. It's a tutorial on Python, HTML, CSS and App Engine, and it's easy to skip the bits you already need. If you don't want to get the book, it's based on the content at http://appenginelearn.com/, which is all available for free.

Full disclosure: I was one of the technical reviewers for the book. I got paid 200 bucks for it, but I don't get any royalties - so there's nothing in it for me making sure it sells well. ;)

Comment: just finished it. let me up and running in no time! Awasome book!

Comment: read now about tech review... but don't mind. Great book anyway :P

Answer (score 3):

IDE integrations

- [Google plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Download_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse) - [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (free)
- [Support for NetBeans](http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/pages/Home) - [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) (free)
- [Integration for IntelliJ](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4254) - [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (isn't free)

---

I think the best way how to start with Eclipse is create your own distribution with plugins what you need.

**Yoxos OnDemand**

- [Online Eclipse configurator](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start)

Comment: No offense, but your first link is completely useless. If the OP didn't know what GAE was, he wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Intellij IDEA with python plugin working with google app engine , The step by step guide available  [Python app engine with IDEA](http://blog.hoofoo.net/2009/09/16/google-app-engine-python-development-on-intellij-idea/)  , This is help full for me to run application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're comfortable with VS, you could start with Eclipse. Its good for the app engine since Google has released a plugin for it, which gives you excellent support - both for the java SDK and GWT.

Eclipse will suit you fine for python too, after you install PyDev. So you can try out both languages to see which one suits you better.

And [code.google.com/appengine](http://code.google.com/appengine) should give you all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming form the Visual Studio world, you're best bet for developing may be using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org).  It has plenty of support for Java, Python and GAE as well as many other sundry things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using Java, I strongly recommend using Eclipse. Google provides tools for eclipse for development and deployment to the App Engine directly from the Eclipse IDE. See this tutorial [Writing Java Hello World for Google app engine](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/04/11/writing-java-hello-world-for-google-app-engine/) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I made a series of short videos, specifically for .NET developers on how best to get started using GAE (with Java in Eclipse) - take a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6971A0258365F21E).