# Deploying an App to Google cloud

Tags: java, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google App Engine, getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108253/google-app-engine-getting-started)

How do I deploy a Java application to a Google cloud? What are the steps involved ? 
I am a beginner at programming so it would be great if you could help me out!

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/ This will help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google AppEngine for Java, Getting Started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/)

Basic steps in a nutshell might include:

- Create an AppEngine project ([here](http://code.google.com/appengine/)).
- install Google plugin ([this](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) is Eclipse plugin) which includes the [AppEngine SDK](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) as well.
- Write your code and test it locally.
- Deploy your application into the real environment once you are satisfied with it.

If you want to use Maven, have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/) Maven plugin. I have used it in some projects.

Comment: Could you please explain the advantages/disadvantages of using Maven ?

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late. The main things I get from Maven are IDE-independence and dependency management (no jar file mess). You can read more about it and other alternative solutions on the web.